# Ionic 6 - RouterLink vendor.js:51830 NG0303: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-card'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using the Angular version of Ionic 6.  I have a reusable component that shows a summary of an event.  On tapping the component I would like to navigate it to  a detail page.  But I get the vendor.js:51830 NG0303: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-card' error.    Below is my code:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let feed of feedData; let i = index" [routerLink]="['/detail/feed.id']">
    <ion-card-content>
     {{ feed.name }}          
    </ion-card-content>
    <p [innerHTML]="feed.feed"></p>
</ion-card>
```

For the component I am importing the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FeedService } from './../../services/feed.service';
```

I am  also importing RouterModule, Routes in the feed.module.ts.

The detail/:id route is registered in the app-routing.module.ts

Comment: you have to add your component in module file.

Comment: I tried but it didn't recognize that.  When you say module file, do you mean feed.moudle.ts?

Comment: Figured it out.  I was adding it at the wrong place. Thanks @NajamUsSaqib for your help.   It needed to go to the declarations: in my feed module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your component in the module of the page the component is being used for under declarations.